# No 's' after male name in genitive case?

Tags: genitive, proper-noun

In the following phrase 
"Die Leiden des jungen Werther"

des jungen Werther is in genitive case, according to the rule masculine nouns  get an s. So why isn't it
"Die Leiden des jungen Werthers" ?